# How to use a Oracle function for the ID in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, sequences

Until recently we used Oracle sequences to generate the IDs of a table. This is now changed, a new ID is now calculated by an Oracle function. Which means that my application needs a change to adept to the new situation. The application is a Spring/Hibernate webApp, which access the Oracle database. This was configured in an hbm.xml as follows:

```
<class name="TableHib" table="TABLENAME" >
    <id name="Id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SEQTABLE</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

Question is of course: what is a solution to use the result of Oracle function for the new value of the ID?

Help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Um... sequences exist for a reason.  Why are you replacing their functionality with a function and what does that function do?

Answer (score 1):

Can you write a Java class that can fetch the value of the Oracle function?  If so, you should be able to define that Java class as your `<generator class>`

**Edit:** To call an Oracle function from Java, see if this works for you:
 [Call Java Oracle Functions From Java program](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/113-call-java-oracle-functions-from-java-program.html) and see the [Java CallableStatement API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)